# AWS Cloudfront cannot translate domain redirects in different cloudfronts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a requirement to transfer all traffic to a different domain, but I'm getting some errors from the cloudfront.

First step, I setup C domain in B origin and everything works fine. But in second step, I set B domain in A origin, I get 403 bad request error from C cloudfront.

In all behavior policies, headers, cookies, and query strings are set to none for both the cache policy and the origin policy.

Traffic Diagram in below:

The red line means can not access
[image]

I also follow the instruction of aws official troubleshoot guide, but it didn't work for me

1. All cloudfront have Cname and ACM(SSL)
2. We didn't use WAF

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-troubleshoot-403-errors

Does someone have same issue ? or am I just hitting the cloudfront's hard limit without knowing it ?